# Cannot filter the data collection

Tags: magento2, database, model, wishlist, resource-model

I'm trying to filter the data collection from 4 hours to now and I have the below code but its not working.

```
public function getWishlistProduct($wishlistid){

$to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$from = strtotime('-4 hours', strtotime($to));
$from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); 

$wishlist= $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('wishlist_id', ['eq'=>$wishlistid])
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('added_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to));
return $wishlist;
      
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Its showing HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using the time() function and the updated code as below. Hope it may helpful to someone:

```
public function getWishlistProduct($wishlistid){

    $time = time();
    $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
    $lastTime = $time - 14400; //60*60*4
    $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);

    $wishlist= $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('wishlist_id', ['eq'=>$wishlistid])
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('added_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to));
    return $wishlist;
          
    }
```

Comment: sound good , Or above my code why showing 500 error because i am missed some column(,)  and i am not sure `$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-4 hour'));
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$from);
    $wishlist= $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('wishlist_id', ['eq'=>$wishlistid])
                                     ->addFieldToFilter('added_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$toDate,'date'=>true));
    return $wishlist;`

Comment: @MohitPatel, Can you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315373/cron-job-is-only-working-when-i-run-the-cron-command-manually?noredirect=1#comment452437_315373 and help me out.